# Raspberry pi: Im using Some code for a Email alert with use of the GPIO ports for LED notifications

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Im using Python the RPi, and found some coding online that would notify me of emails that come in and light up an LED on the GPIO ports

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, feedparser, time

DEBUG = 1

USERNAME = ""
PASSWORD = ""

NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 1
MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 60

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GREEN_LED = 18
RED_LED = 23
GPIO.setup (GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RED_LED, GPIO.OUT)

while True:

    newmails = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])

    if DEBUG:
        print "You have" newmails, "new emails!"

        if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
            GPIO.output (GREEN_LED, True)
            GPIO.output (RED_LED, False)

        else:

            GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
            GPIO.output(RED_LED, True)

        time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And Python says that the " by the first print is invalid. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Is this an exact copy-paste from the code on your machine? It looks like you're missing a comma after `"You have"` and before `newmails`.